# Complicated Notepad++ copy, replace, and insert

Tags: json, regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a list of various unrelated strings on separate lines in Notepad++.

```
127.0.0.1
badwebsite.com
dontgohere.com
```

How do I use Notepad++ to create something like the below?

```
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"127.0.0.1","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"127.0.0.1","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
```

I basically want to copy the contents of the line to use again.  First, I need to prepend it with this:

```
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"
```

Next is the original line contents:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Then, I would insert the following content:

```
","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"
```

Afterwards, the original contents of the line would be repeated:

```
127.0.0.1
```

Finally, I would append it with the following:

```
","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
```

I do know that I would use the replace feature with regular expression to search for `^` and replace with `whatever I want at the start of the line` and I would search for `$` and replace with `whatever I want at the end of the line`.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to repeat the contents of a line while inserting a string.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  `badwebsite.com` appears nowhere in your expected JSON output, so why even consider it as part of the input?

Comment: `badwebsite.com` was just an example of one of the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use `Replace` with regular expression enabled and find:

```
^(.+)$
```

which finds a set of characters between the start and end of a line and stores them in a capture group which we can refer to using `$1` in the replacement string:

```
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"$1","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"$1","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
```

Output:

```
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"127.0.0.1","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"127.0.0.1","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"badwebsite.com","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"badwebsite.com","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
{"blocked":true,"flagged":true,"string":"dontgohere.com","javaClass":"com.untangle.uvm.app.GenericRule","name":null,"description":"dontgohere.com","readOnly":null,"id":null,"category":null,"enabled":null}
```